# Manage big data in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, bigdata

Our team is facing a problem of querying a large amount of data on sql server blocks inserting into the table.

We are working on a .NET project which involves saving and querying a large amount of data. The project contains two databases, one is a Realtime database and the other one is a Historical database, both are SQL Server databases, and they live on different machine. The two databases have the exactly same table structure, and there are only four tables.

The Realtime DB contains a small amount of real-time data, and the data inside is constantly being updated. The historical DB contains all the updates history. When the project runs, it will shoot update queries to the Realtime DB, and insert queries into the Historical DB. Each day about 2 million inserts will be executed on the Historical DB. The queries are executed Asynchronously.

The Historical DB will also be used for data retrieval and reporting purposes. People will run queries on the server, what queries they will run are out of our control. The problem we are facing right now is that when a query that returns a lot of rows is running, the connection pool will be full within a short time, as a result connection timeout would occur and data will be lost.

We have tried tweaking indexes on the table, increasing the max size of connection pool and increasing the timeout time, but none of them will solve the problem primarily. In production the project will run for 5 years, at that time there will be 4 billion rows in the database.

I guess my real question is how people usually deal with big data in SQL server, how to manage insert and select at the same time on a table that has millions or billions of rows.

Comment: If you're only inserting data into the historic db's tables & are using single statement queries try setting your transaction isolation level to read uncommitted.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Thanks for the reply. Please see my comment to Paul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your architecture has a basic error in that it doesn't consider the historical database as real-time. It actually is, in spite of its name, because data is being inserted in real time. Call it what you will and split inserts and updates but you will still need a fix for your current architecture.

To solve this issue you can add/reconfigure for a third db conceptually which will decouple the inserts temporally. Instead of feeding the historical database in real time you can create a job (e.g. SSIS package) that inserts rows into the database in bulk at off-peak time(s). This could be once a day, say at 2 am, or multiple times of day. It depends on your business. Periodic bulk loading would allow fast bulk transfers while not slowing down the queries performed on the historical data, assuming that the off-peak transfer and the querying happen at different times. The trade off is that your historical data is not up to the second, but that may be good enough. Of course you would need to store the real time inserts somewhere between transfers. This is why I mentioned a 3rd db, but you could simply fold that temp storage into your real time db and not affect the back end users.

This is how things are done frequently, to answer your last question directly, in the wild. You separate your transaction processing db (the real-time db) from your analytical processing (historical, OLAP, data warehouse, etc.) by some period transfer process that tries to stay out of the way of the transaction processing and the querying, usually by some scheduled task. You could also use a queueing system (e.g. MSMQ, RabbitMQ etc.) as an intermediate store between your real-time and historic database. This would decouple the two databases while also allowing for a closer to real-time availability of historical data for querying.

If scheduled bulk transfers or queues are not a viable options you could denormalize. Figure out what data is getting collected and how it may be getting aggregated and create denormalized tables specifically for those queries.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you said does make sense. Last week the dudes who manage the db servers updated the RAM from 4GB to 8GB. After that our team spent a whole day trying to recreate the issue, but unfortunately we didn't get it. We thought it might be due to low RAM. We have decided to leave it for a couple of days, let the data size grow and see what happens. If the same issue happens again, a 3rd conceptually db would be our next move. Cheers

Comment: @BboyJeans: More RAM will solve a lot of issues, in the short run, but in the long run there's a limit to what a single machine can do. Though your pain is down for now I would suggest being proactive with the architectural changes. The pain can get much worse if your team waits for the slowdown again before acting.